# PySpark Join after GroupBy

Tags: python, join, group-by, pyspark

I have two dataframes and what I would like to do is to join them per groups/partitions. How can I do it in PySpark?

The first df contains 3 time series identified by an id a timestamp and a value. Noticed that the time series contains some gap (missing days)

[image]

The second df contains a time series without gaps

[image]

The result I want to reach is

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`Left join` on second df with **`coalesce`** will work for this case.

**`Example:`**

```
df.show()
#---+--------+-----+
#tag|      ts|value|
#---+--------+-----+
#  a|01-01-19|   45|
#  a|03-01-19|   89|
#  a|04-01-19|   24|
#  a|05-01-19|  778|
#---+--------+-----+

df1.show()
#+--------+
#|      ts|
#+--------+
#|01-01-19|
#|02-01-19|
#|03-01-19|
#|04-01-19|
#|05-01-19|
#+--------+

df1.alias("t1").join(df.alias("t2"),col("t1.ts")==col("t2.ts"),"left").\
selectExpr("coalesce(t1.ts,t2.ts) as ts","tag","value").\
orderBy("ts").\
show()

#+--------+----+-----+
#|      ts| tag|value|
#+--------+----+-----+
#|01-01-19|   a|   45|
#|02-01-19|null| null|
#|03-01-19|   a|   89|
#|04-01-19|   a|   24|
#|05-01-19|   a|  778|
#+--------+----+-----+
```

Comment: The complexity is to join df1 n times as the number of tags. In your example you didn't consider this complexity.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it:

```
df2 = (
    df2
    .withColumn("tag", F.array([F.lit("a"), F.lit("b"), F.lit("c")]))
    .withColumn("ts", F.explode("ts"))
)

df_out = df1.join(df2, ["tag","ts"], "outer")
```

If you wanted to have a dynamically generated list of tags you could create that from df1.